# Retrieving req.body with connect-busboy

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express, multipartform-data

When posting a multipart form, I'm able to retrieve files using connect-busboy, but am not able to fetch values from req.body. I assume that I need to hook `req.busboy.on('field')`, but don't know where to place this in a way that still allows me to utilize the functions that are currently working on uploaded files.

---

**routes.js**

```
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(busboy());
  app.route('/upload')
    .post(function (req, res) {
      req.pipe(req.busboy);
      upload.createImg(req, res);
    });
```

---

**upload.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');

exports.createImg = function (req, res) {
  var fstream,
      path = './uploads/temp/';

  req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
    fstream = fs.createWriteStream(path + filename);
    file.pipe(fstream);
    fstream.on('close', function() {
      fs.readFile(path + filename, function (err, data) {
        // need help here
      });
    });
  });
});
```

---

In the code sample above, I am able to retrieve the uploaded files, which I am then successfully manipulating with ImageMagick. The problem, however, is that I want to retrieve data from req.body, such as `req.height`, `req.width`, etc. It seems busboy is not finished working its magic, though, as `req.body` is `undefined`.

How can I go about passing `req.body` along to my functions within `fstream.on('close', ...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want/expect the multiparty/formidable-style API but using busboy instead, you should look at [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

Comment: This added layer is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this busboy `field` event to get parse data -

```
req.busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val) {
    console.log(fieldname, val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen to `file`, `field` and `finish` events. `finish` event will trigger after parsing the form. You can use `file` and `field` events to cache information and using them in `finish` event to do post processing after handling both `file` and `field` events. Remember to handle the stream if you listent to `file` event. Otherwise rest of the events will not trigger. [Read BusBoy Docs Here](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy#busboy-special-events).

For example,

```
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {

    let uploadedFileName = null;
    let userId = null;

    req.busboy.on('file', (fieldName, file, fileName) => {

        let uploadPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', fileName);    
        uploadedFileName = fileName; // let's store this to use in finish event

        let stream = fs.createWriteStream(uploadPath);
        // file stream is consumed here. If it's not consumed, finish event wont trigger.
        file.pipe(stream); 
    });

    req.busboy.on('field', (fieldName, val) => {
        if (fieldName == 'userId') {
            userId = val; //cache some more fields
        }
    })

    req.busboy.on('finish', () => {

        // You can access both values and both above event handles have run before this handler.
        console.log(userId, uploadedFileName);

        
    })


    req.pipe(req.busboy);

}
```